# Duplicate a floating point number with Ruby in Sketchup

Tags: ruby, floating-point, sketchup

Is it possible to duplicate a float number array as a variable to a new variable in **ruby with sketchup**? I have tried both .clone and .dup, but no luck (see below).

```
a = [1.1,2.2,3.3]
b = [a.dup,a.dup,a.dup] #Returns "TypeError: can't dup Float"
b = [a.clone,a.clone,a.clone] #Returns "TypeError: can't clone Float"
```

Any other ways of duplicating an arrayed variable containing floats in **ruby with sketchup**?

EDIT:
This is what I am trying to do:

```
a = [1.1,2.2,3.3]
x = [4.4,5.5,6.6]
b = [a,x]
b[0][1] += 1.1
b[1][1] += 1.1
```

so that `a == [1.1,2.2,3.3]`, `x == [4.4,5.5,6.6]` and `b == [[1.1,3.3,3.3],[4.4,6.6,6.6]]`

I now realise that both .clone and .dup work in Ruby itself (Thanks to Amadan and Sami Kuhmonen)

Comment: Just assign it. They’re integral types, they can’t be cloned.

Comment: Not for 1001 times, I'm not...any other ways or is that literally the only way to do it?

Comment: Why would you need another way to do it than simple assignment?

Comment: As in simply use ```b=a```?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that

Comment: With Ruby, if ```b = a``` I go ```b += 1``` we have a problem, because ```b == 2.1``` **and** ```a == 2.1```

Comment: @Poyda: That's not how primitive types work. Try it yourself.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen & Amadan: Thanks for pointing that out. See updated question.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: What do you mean by “They’re integral types”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see what your updated question has to do with the original one, but here's two ways to do what you wanted:

```
b = [a.dup, b.dup]
b[0][1] += 1.1
b[1][1] += 1.1
```

or

```
b.map! { |r| r.dup.tap { |r2| r2[1] += 1.1 } }
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain myself very well. This now messes with the x and a values, and I don't want it to do that.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice `a` and `x` were unchanged. Will change in a sec.

Comment: Just to let you know I was using Ruby in  Sketchup. Should I close this question because it *does* work in Ruby, or edit it?

Comment: The second option works in Sketchup, however in both Ruby and Sketchup Ruby, I have the result ```3.3000000000000003``` if one of the values is ```3.3```?

Comment: Yep, not Ruby's fault: check out [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). In Ruby you can use [other datatypes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Rational.html) to overcome it; for example, `(1.1r + 2.2r).to_f` will give you `3.3`.

Comment: as in change over the floats to rationals, then back again...right, thanks for that